# Remember network share user name but not password

Tags: network, password

I regularly connect to a remote file store (webDAV) that uses different credentials to my OSX user account. I don't want to save the password to my OSX keychain, but would prefer not to have to retype both my user name AND password every time.

Is there a way to make OSX remember the user name for that share but prompt for the passowrd?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How are you connecting? If it's something that lets you enter (& memorize) an explicit URL (e.g. in the Finder's Connect to Server dialog), you can enter the URL in the form "`https://username@server`". If the URL processing does its job right (the Finder's does), it'll use that as the default username when it asks for authentication.